# VBA to concatenate Strings

Tags: sql, excel, vba, concatenation

I have some VBA code that strings together various cells (always in succession) that when put together create a SQL query(End users have drop down menus to create a dynamic report).  This is not ideal as I have to list out all the cells as well as I get errors for the VBA being too long.  See sample below

```
Sub Custom_Query

Dim strsql As String

If Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("B1") = "Dog" And Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("E1") = "Food_Consumption" Then

strsql = Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A362")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A363")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A364")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A365")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A366")

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
     Debug.Print strsql
    .CommandText = strsql

    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").Refresh

ElseIf Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("B1") = "Dog" And Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("E1") = "Bathroom_Breaks" Then

strsql = Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A372")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A373")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A374")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A375")
strsql = strsql & vbNewLine
strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A376")

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
     Debug.Print strsql
    .CommandText = strsql

    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").Refresh

End if

End Sub
```

I would like to use something along the following. However, I can't quite figure out the syntax to get it working.

```
Sub Custom_Query()

Dim strsql As String

If Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("B1") = "Dog" And Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("E1") = "Food_Consumption" Then

    For i = 362 To 366
        strsql = Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A" & i) & vbNewLine
    Next i

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
     Debug.Print strsql
    .CommandText = strsql

    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").Refresh

ElseIf Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("B1") = "Dog" And Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("E1") = "Bathroom_Breaks" Then

    For i = 372 To 376
        strsql = Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A" & i) & vbNewLine
    Next i

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
     Debug.Print strsql
    .CommandText = strsql

    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").Refresh

End if

End Sub
```

Any tips to get in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: strsql = strsql & Worksheets("Custom_Queries").Range("A" & i) & vbNewLine

Comment: You have the answer in the first code block, using `strsql = strsql & `.

Comment: You don't need the newlines either, although you might need spaces.

Comment: Off-topic; be aware of [sql injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) when building dynamic queries.

Comment: I forgot an important piece (sigh).  There are "if statements" that dictate which cells are combined together to create the SQL query.  I have updated the code in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't able to find a solution  that matched what I wanted to do in my OP but I did create a work around. Instead of creating the dynamic SQL statements in one large VBA section, i created each SQL query in its own VBA section and then called it in the main query.

```
Sub custom_Query()

If Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("Selection") = "Dog" And Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("E1") = "Food_Consumption" Then

Call Food_Consumption

ElseIf Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("Selection") = "Dog" And Worksheets("Animal_Entry").Range("E1") = "Bathroom Breaks" Then

Call Bathroom_Break

end IF
End Sub
```